# jQuery uploadify I/O error UNIX

Tags: php, jquery, unix, uploadify

I've a problem with jQuery uploadify script and I didn't found any solution.
I've integrated this script on my project and everything is working fine on a Windows server(localhost) but when I try to run it on an UNIX server and I/O error is risen. 
This only happens when I try to upload a file that already exists on uploading folder. On Windows the file is overwritten but a UNIX I get and I/O error.

Please if you have any solutions I'll be very grateful.

Here is the server side code which I think is the problem(PHP code):

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_REQUEST['folder'].'/';
    $targetFile = str_replace('//', '/', $targetPath).$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    if (file_exists($targetFile)) unlink($targetFile);
    copy($tempFile, $targetFile);
    echo "1";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

First few things to check:

- Which user owns the file that exists?
- Which user owns the directory that the file is in?
- Which user is running your PHP script?
- What are the permissions on the file itself?
- What are the permissions on the directory that the file is in?

The reason I ask these questions is because it may be a simple permissions problem. The user running the `unlink` and file create of the target file will need write access to the directory. It's possible that the user that's running the script is *not* the one that owns the directory or file, in which case you may have to open up the permissions a bit.

Of course, that's just conjecture on my part but that's the first thing I'd be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) instead of a copy.

But most likely your problem is due to a permissions problem. Can you upload any file to the folder? Have you checked that the files already in the folder (those you want to overwrite) have the same permissions as a newly uploaded one? My guess would be that you copied the files to the folder using (S)FTP and that they have a different owner/permissions so you can't overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the possible permissions issues mentioned by paxdiablo and wimvds, also check the case of your filename & path.  Unlike windows, unix filesystems are case-sensitive.